# using .style to conditionally format cells in pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use `.style` to conditionally format records where the actual numbers are smaller than the `'Budget'` column.

I've tried using the code below:

```
percent_scrap = (percent_scrap.style
    .format("{0:,.2f}%")
    .apply(lambda x: x == 'background-color: red'
        if x > x['Bud Yield']
        else '',
        axis = 1
    )
)
```

but the lambda function produces the error:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I've tried creating a "mask" dataframe with `False` being mapped to `'background-color: red'` and then passing it to the `style` function but could not figure out how to do this properly either.

I'm sure there's a better way.

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're lambda function mixes returning a single element and a test over an array object, hence the error.

You would be better off using something like:

```py
styler.apply(lambda s: np.where(s>df["budget"], "color:red", None), axis=0)
```

This will evaluate each column as a series, `s`, compared against the dataframe column `budget` and return an array of styles to be applied for each of those columns.

You can amend the `apply` method to exclude the `budget` column:

```py
styler.apply(lambda s: np.where(s>df["budget"], "color:red", None), axis=0, subset=[col for col in df.columns if col != "budget"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure it out:

```
percent_scrap = (percent_scrap.style
             .apply(lambda x: ["color:red; font-weight:bold" if v < x.iloc[-1] and v != 0 else "" for v in x],axis = 1)         
             .format("{0:,.2f}%")
            )
```

This allowed me to format all columns in the dataframe based on the values in the very last column